# Does the set of such ordered pairs exist in mathematics?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $S=\lbrace (a, b), (\emptyset, d), (e, \emptyset),.. \rbrace$ be a set of ordered pairs, where $\emptyset$ in the elements $(\emptyset,  d)$ etc. are null or, empty object.

But I have never seen (in literature) such ordered element with its one of the objects being an empty or, a null (but, I have such sets in my mind). Please help me clearing my doubt as whether such ordered pairs exists in a set?

Comment: do we know anything more about $S$? what is the next entry in $S$?

Comment: @supinf $S$ is just a notation or, an arbitrary set of ordered pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly possible.

You might for example start with a set $X$ and consider its power set $\mathcal P(X)=2^X$, and then consider ordered pairs from the power set  $S=\mathcal P(X)\times \mathcal P(X)=\left(2^X\right)^2$.

This last will include objects of the form you are thinking about.  As a short example, if $X= \{x\}$ then $S=\{(X,X), (X,\emptyset), (\emptyset,X), (\emptyset,\emptyset)   \}=\{(\{x\},\{x\}), (\{x\},\emptyset), (\emptyset,\{x\}), (\emptyset,\emptyset)   \}$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, such ordered pairs where one of the component is an empty set can exist.
They appear not often in mathematics, but it can still happen occasionally.

Answer (score 1):

The ordered pair $(a,b)$ by definition from [1] is the set
$$\big\{ \{a\},\{a,b\}\big\}$$
so, you may put $a=\varnothing$, it is OK.
[1] Lin SY, Lin YF. Set theory with applications. Mancorp Pub; 1985.